# Running a vb dotnet application on a LAn

Tags: vb.net

I have created a vb.net application using Mysql from Xamp as my database. Now i created a hotspot using my phone so that i can get my application on both computers to do CRUD operations on the vb.net application but its not working. The application is only working on my development machine but not on the second computer i am running it. This is my connection string

```
Dim Connection As New MySqlConnection("server=192.168.43.50; user=root; password=''; database=registry")
```

The application is working fine on where i have started the xamp server but i am  not able to connect to the application from the second computer on the same Lan

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. it might be helpful to you.

```
    Dim Connection As New MySqlConnection("server=192.168.43.50;Port=1234; user=root; 
password=''; database=registry")
```

Please refer : https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: try with port no : 3306 this is for Xampp port no

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-change-the-port-of-a-MySQL-server-in-XAMPP change port in Xampp and try the above link help to how to change port no

Comment: I have changed the port but still not working. The thing is this when i change the ip address to localhost only the development machine where mysql server is running is able to access the application but when i change the ip address to 192.168.43.50 then  neither of us ie. both the development machine and the other laptop on the lan can login into the Application.

Comment: check the port is open or not ?

Comment: @ sk2185 Yes its opened i can access phpmyadmin

Comment: are u checked firewall block.

Comment: @ sk2185 i can also access phpmyadmin on the second machine

Comment: read that but didnt work for me . Finally got it working by adding skip-grant-tables under [mysqld] in my.ini file of mysql in xamp